# Edit own question doesn't pick up changes just done

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

While editing this answer [DOS batch FOR loop with FIND.exe is stripping out blank lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811992/dos-batch-for-loop-with-find-exe-is-stripping-out-blank-lines/14642856#14642856) of mine, yesterday and today, think I had found a bug.

After finishing doing a major overhall of the question, realised that I had one missed one small detail, but upon clicking on the below:

[image]



Got into the edit screen to see this:



[image]



Seems the review screen also agrees with this now outdated view of the question



[image]



I tried a page refresh ignoring cache (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd>) with no change in what revision the `edited 23 minutes ago` took me to / made available.

I have also had this happen to me second most recently, earlier today. In editing this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/166110/revisions, I forgot a couple of changes I wanted to make, only to go in and not notice that I wasn't working off the last edit, but instead the one before.

Comment: All appears fine for me.

Comment: The same second that I was notified of your comment to this question animuson, I submitted my re-editing for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/166110/revisions. However, instead of bringing me back to the question, I was taken back to the page when I noticed *some* of the edits I have done appeared in the Rev dropdown (http://i.imgur.com/Zyhuulh.png). The other main question in the above still shows the same as screenshot above for me.

Comment: Okay, looking at this question on another PC, the revisions / edit page works normally. Considering these are all generic URL's, and I used Ctrl+f5 reloads several times, I am still wondering what is going on here.